# SAS disk, red light means it's failing?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

My server uses SAS 15k RPM disks. One of them has a red light. AFAIK, that means that it needs to be replaced; but it's not used intensively - actually the server was still in the configuration stage, and only 2 months old.

What can it be? May be it's S.M.A.R.T failure? Also, when I was away the workers hard reset the server two times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hard drives can fail at any time.  Far better that it fails now, while it's well under warranty and before it's in heavy production usage, than when you can't afford the downtime and/or performance degradation to replace and rebuild the array.

Get it replaced and move on.

Answer (score 4):

Try re-seating the drive, sometimes they just need a swift kick - but, if that doesn't help: a wise man listens to a drive when it's telling you that it's dead.

Get it swapped under warranty.